# How to open a file with .3 extension?

Tags: 10.04

I have a very important file which in ubuntu says .3 extention. How to open it?
Please help me!

File type says its .bin file? According to me it should be either picture, pdf or doc!

Answer (score 2):

Alternately, numerical suffixes are often used for the parts of split archives. If you have a .1 and .2 file with the same prefix, you may need to join them.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu does not use file suffixes to identify file types.

See [magic numbers](http://www.linfo.org/magic_number.html)

What does `head file.3` show you ?

What happens if you try to open it with eog (eye of gnome), evince, or openoffice ?